# iOS: set UITextView line spacing from Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, uitextview

Inside of Interface Builder, is it possible to set paragraph style properties like line spacing for a UITextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can set paragraph style properties using `Attributed` Test instead of plain text. Please refer the attached screenshot with steps.

[image]